# NSUser Defaults - Saving 3 variables together and then fetching

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, nsuserdefaults

I'm using `NSUserDefaults` for persistent storage in my app. It is a game where after the game ends the score, together with the date and name (entered by user) must be stored and then shown in an table view. My code so far is:

```
import UIKit

class LeaderboardVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

var finishedGame = 0
var gameScore:Int! = 0
var name:String!
var date:String!
var score:Int!
var scoreData = [NSArray]()
var defaults = UserDefaults.standard

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if finishedGame == 1{
        saveNew()
    }

    self.tableView.delegate = self
    self.tableView.dataSource = self


}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true



}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}

func saveNew() {

    let enterNameAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Please Enter Your Name", message: "This will be used to place you in the leaderboards", preferredStyle: .alert)

    enterNameAlert.addTextField { (textField:UITextField) -> Void in
        textField.placeholder = "Name"
        textField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationType.words
        textField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionType.no
        textField.clearsOnBeginEditing = true
        textField.clearsOnInsertion = true
        textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewMode.always
        textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.default

    }
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)

    let confirmAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Confirm", style: .default) { (action:UIAlertAction) in

        let currentTime = Date()
        let timeFormatter = DateFormatter()
        timeFormatter.locale = Locale.current
        timeFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm dd/MM/yy"
        let convertedTime = timeFormatter.string(from: currentTime) //date
        let enteredName = enterNameAlert.textFields?.first?.text //name

        // set object of date,name and score here
    }

    enterNameAlert.addAction(cancelAction)
    enterNameAlert.addAction(confirmAction)
    self.present(enterNameAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! LeaderBoardCell

    cell.dateLabel?.text =
    cell.dateLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    cell.scoreLabel?.text =
    cell.scoreLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    cell.nameLabel?.text =
    cell.nameLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return scoreData.count
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
}
```

There are 3 labels in the cell one for each of the 3 values which must be displayed. How do I set these values using `NSUserDefaults` (They must be together FOR example score:500 goes with name:John and so on)?

**EDIT - NEW CODE**

```
import UIKit
```

class LeaderboardVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

```
var finishedGame = 0
var gameScore:Int! = 0
var defaults = UserDefaults.standard
var newUserArray = NSMutableArray()

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if finishedGame == 1{
        saveNew()
    }

    self.tableView.delegate = self
    self.tableView.dataSource = self


}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true



}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}

func saveNew() {

    let enterNameAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Please Enter Your Name", message: "This will be used to place you in the leaderboards", preferredStyle: .alert)

    enterNameAlert.addTextField { (textField:UITextField) -> Void in
        textField.placeholder = "Name"
        textField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationType.words
        textField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionType.no
        textField.clearsOnBeginEditing = true
        textField.clearsOnInsertion = true
        textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewMode.always
        textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.default

    }
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)

    let confirmAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Confirm", style: .default) { (action:UIAlertAction) in

        let currentTime = Date()
        let timeFormatter = DateFormatter()
        timeFormatter.locale = Locale.current
        timeFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm dd/MM/yy"
        let convertedTime = timeFormatter.string(from: currentTime)
        let enteredName = enterNameAlert.textFields?.first?.text

        let newUserData = self.defaults.object(forKey: "UserData") as! NSArray
        let newUserArray = NSMutableArray(array: newUserData)

        let newUserRecord = [
            "Name"  : enteredName!,
            "Score" : String(self.gameScore),
            "Date"    : convertedTime
            ] as [String : String]

        newUserArray.add(newUserRecord)
        self.defaults.set(newUserArray, forKey: "UserData")
        self.defaults.synchronize()
        print(newUserArray)
        print("hello")
        print(self.defaults)


    }

    enterNameAlert.addAction(cancelAction)
    enterNameAlert.addAction(confirmAction)
    self.present(enterNameAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! LeaderBoardCell
    let userData = defaults.object(forKey: "UserData") as! NSArray

    cell.dateLabel?.text = "Date: \(((userData.object(at: indexPath.row) as! [String:Any])["Date"] as! String))"
    cell.dateLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    cell.scoreLabel?.text = "Score: \(((userData.object(at: indexPath.row) as! [String:Any])["Score"] as! String))"
    cell.scoreLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    cell.nameLabel?.text = "Name: \(((userData.object(at: indexPath.row) as! [String:Any])["Name"] as! String))"
    cell.nameLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return newUserArray.count
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
```

}

Comment: If you have multiple users, I suggest you to save data in Core Data
Else use a Dictionary object and store in UserDefaults

Comment: I tried using Core Data but it wasn't working for me in this case therefore I want to use NSUserDefaults. How can I do it in NSUserDefaults?

Comment: How many users are there for the game. As UserDefaults will work only for a single user and a single object will be stored

Comment: The game will only be played on 1 device and doesnt feature any online functionality. All I require is after each game the score,name and date are stored and shown in the table view

Comment: Can you share your structure of ScoreData array as that will be your datasource. scoreData consists of what?

Comment: Its on the top of the code. I put it as NSArray however it isnt definitive I just put it as I was unsure

Comment: Reading some articles on google now and I might need to just use apples gamcenter

Answer (score 0):

You can set dictionary to UserDefaults (that's for 3 values at one time). To do a leaderboard you'll need to hold this dictionaries in array.

```
let scoreDict: [String : Any] = ["name": "John", "score": 500, "date": NSDate()]
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

let scoresKey = "scores"

var currentScores: [Any] = defaults.array(forKey: scoresKey) ?? []
currentScores.append(scoreDict)

defaults.set(currentScores, forKey: scoresKey)
defaults.synchronize()
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get as much but I just found that you need to add some elements to your `scoreData` for the tableview datasource

Here you can add the complete object in `UserDefaults`

```
//Make your scoreData as MutableArray
var scoreData = NSMutableArray()

// Record of a user
let user = [
            "name"  : "John",
            "score" : 10,
            "id"    : 20
        ] as [String : Any]

scoreData.add(user)
defaults.set(scoreData, forKey: "UserData")
```

How to fetch them

```
let userData = defaults.object(forKey: "UserData") as! NSArray
print((userData.object(at: 0) as! [String:Any])["name"] as! String)
print((userData.object(at: 0) as! [String:Any])["score"] as! Int)
print((userData.object(at: 0) as! [String:Any])["id"] as! Int)
```

I have printed them on console and only the 0th index. You can print them on your Label with `indexPath.row` elements.

**EDIT**
In order to add a new record, first Fetch the old data from userDefaults

```
let newUserData = defaults.object(forKey: "UserData") as! NSArray
```

Then convert it into mutable array because we want to add a new user record. I could have done it while fetching but on fetching from `UserDefaults` it gives a immutable object no matter we type cast to `NSMutableArray`. So convert the `newUserData` to mutable object

```
let newUserMutableArray = NSMutableArray(array: newUserData)
```

Add a new record

```
// New record
let newUserRecord = [
    "name"  : "Rajan",
    "score" : 20,
    "id"    : 30
    ] as [String : Any]

newUserMutableArray.add(newUserRecord)
```

Save it again

```
defaults.set(newUserMutableArray, forKey: "UserData")
```

And again fetch the way it is mentioned above. Now the fetched `NSArray` will contain two elements.
I still prefer to use core data in this case as the handling will become lot easy.

**EDIT**
After fetching

```
scoreDataArray = defaults.object(forKey: "UserData") as! NSArray
```

Reload your table

```
self.yourTableView.reloadData()
```

Your table view datasource methods will be like

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return scoreDataArray.count
}
```

In your `cellForRowAt` datasource method

```
cell.scoreLabel?.text = scoreDataArray.object(at: indexPath.row) as! [String:Any])["score"] as! String
```

Comment: thanks. How would I make it so I can print every index avaiable? Just loop through?

Comment: Seems to be working fine to add the object however I tried to add the fetch part of your code in the cellForRow method however it isnt showing. I think I need to fetch first at like a viewWillAppear method and then use the indexPath.row as you said. How do you recommend I do this?

Comment: First fill your complete score data array and save it. Then later on fetch it by calling some function make the data source accordingly and reload the table. In this case userData should be datasource for the table

Comment: Ok thank you another question, would this method work for more than one entries?

Comment: @John_Sm1 yes it will. See the edit in the answer. But Istill prefer core data in this case

Comment: Yes ok thanks will update the code. Yh I prefer CoreData too used in in lot of previous projects however after migrating to Swift3 starting giving me loads of issues in this case so had to try another method

Comment: Also kind of confused with the edit now. What happens to the scoreData? Also does this mean I can only add 2 users or does this code handle further users too?

Comment: You can use the same old variable scoreData which is a mutable object rather than creating newUserMutableArray. Just reinitiaize it as I did for newUserMutableArray

Comment: Hi, All The Values are being added to the NSUserDefaults as I have printed the array and it is showing all the values however my current method for showing them in the table view isnt working as they arent appearing. I update the post with my current code. What do I need to change/add to get that working?

Comment: Fetch indexpath.row from your mutable array in cellforrow and assign to the text of the label

Comment: How will I do that for each specific value? Ive attempted it as shown in the updated code but doesnt really seem to be working for me?

Comment: See how to populate table view in iOS. You haven't set anything to your labels yet

Comment: Yh I understand but im confused how to implement the indexPath.row in this case as Ive tried already in the ".object(at: indexPath.row)" however It didnt work. What do I have to do?

Comment: Just like I am fetching the array with index 0. Replace the 0 with indexpath.row and set accordingly in cellforrowatindex. Also make sure to reload table whenever you have fetched everything to a mutable array

Comment: Yh I've done that already as you can seen in the updated code in the post. I did what you just said but it didnt do anything? Am I missing something or doing something incorrectly?

Comment: Yes you are doing wrong.newUserArray is your datasource and you have filled with the userData variable. Also reload table once

Comment: Ive tried swapping where it says userData(object) to newUserArray(object) and reloaded the table yet its not working. Could you maybe edit your solution with what I should be doing?

Comment: @John_Sm1 You really need to focus on basics of table view.

Comment: @John_Sm1 Have you really implemented Core Data ever. No issues for me in Swift 3. If you have implemented Core Data before, you would not have taken this approach ever.